# Using Angular UI router I would like to highlight abstract parent state and link to child concrete state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My main navigation should highlight items whenever any of the child states are being active i.e.

```
<li ui-sref-active="selected">
    <a ui-sref="settings">Settings</a>
</li>
```

Suppose these states

```
$stateProvider
    .state({
        abstract: true,
        name: 'settigns',
        url: '/settings',
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })
    .state({
        name: 'settings.user',
        url: '',
        templateUrl: require('./user.html'),
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })
    .state({
        name: 'settings.company',
        url: '/company',
        templateUrl: require('./company.html'),
        reloadOnSearch: false
    });
```

Upper HTML will correctly highlight my `li` whenever I would be in any of the settings pages, but link itself points to an abstract state so it doesn't work.

**How should I set my link state?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anybody stumbles on this here's the solution that works without any additional code:

```
<li ui-sref-active="{ selected: 'settings' }">
    <a ui-sref="settings.user">Settings</a>
</li>
```